# $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] Reliability Factors with HTTP Image Requests

Tags: php, cross-browser, referrer, spoofing, server

**It has been said not to trust the $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] because it can either..**

1. Be spoofed
2. Not set by the browser

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Accepting the fact that it can be spoofed, my question is now this.. Which browsers don't set the variable and do the ones that do, always set it consistently, on HTTP requests for images.

After doing some testing in all the major browsers including IE6 and up, I have yet to find one that does not set $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], or does not set it correctly.

Can we say that all browsers actually do set the variable, or that the majority of them do? Is there a list of browsers that fail?

Comment: Have you tried running url fetch scripts from a server on a cron job? I'm not totally sure the unreliability of http_referer was due to the common user. It may have been more a warning that anyone looking to circumvent your safeguards which depend on http_referer can easily do so.

Comment: it's not that browser don't set it, it's that you can't **TRUST** it. Just because it's "usually" correct, doesn't mean you can assume it's "always" correct.

Comment: @MarcB But are there any browsers or cases where it's simply not set?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can even give a list of browsers/UA's that would be consistent in this regard.

Consider:

1. Bots and Spiders.
2. Javascript can be used to alter the referer.
3. Direct Access.
4. Related to #1, lots of other automated HTTP clients.
5. Most browser "privacy" extensions, referer switching extensions, incognito/private browsing mode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From The Web Application Hacker's Handbook:

> The Referer header is strictly optional according to w3.org standards.
>   Hence **although most browsers implement** it, using it to control
>   application functionality should be regarded as a “hack.”

Because a hacker can intercept an HTTP request using appropriate toos, and can modify it before sending an HTTP request, it should not be used to control any application functionality.